# "Had been checked and then" vs "Had been checked before"

Tags: sentence-construction

is it correct to say?
"This had been checked and then send it to you"
Or
"This had been checked before send it to you"

I would like to know use of Had been correct or not.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for any of:

"This had been checked and then sent to you." or

"This had been checked before it was sent to you." or

"This had been checked before [I, s/he, they, Sally] sent it to you."

Either there needs to be a subject for "send" (whomever is did the sending) or that part also needs to be in the passive voice.  And since the sending happened in the past, it needs to be in the past tense ("sent").

Comment: I think "This had been checked before sending." is also possible.